# If you need to enter your skype name to link your account

Tags: login, flow

I'm working on a website which can be connected with Skype and the user has some benefit from it. In case if you need to enter your Skype name to link your account, and then click on your name - after the click should Skype be automatically connected with this website, or does it need some better confirmation? (The whole process is being done on this website)

Now the flow works like this:

user enters id -> click on the right one from the list -> he is connected

Comment: What would be the process for a user to be disconnected from Skype? I expect that you will need to make the behaviour consistent for connecting and disconnecting from the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Skype services, Skype will verify the user and ask the user to login. But I don't think that is the case here since you are somehow populating Skype users in the dropdown. So, there isn't really a need for confirmation in the flow. If it all about displaying the Skype name in a user's profile, a confirmation should not be necessary. You should have a confirmation if there is a risk to having the wrong Skype name. For example, if you are trying to interview someone on Skype and the username is wrong, there will be a huge problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

One more thing. In case when you have to choose(find) your own Skype username in a list of maybe 30-50 similar?

Example: Your username is Ren.something, and you wrote just a part of your username - Ren, and you got 30 usernames in the list.

And you find Ren.something in that list and you click on it. So, is better to have confirmation(maybe some popup modal - Is this your Skype username?), or just one click on that username is enough for link your account to the website?

Comment: @NemanjaJoksic In that case you need some sort of submit button after selection. False clicks happen all the time, imagine if someone is scrolling the list on mobile if they release the scroll too soon it may count as a click and start the linking process.